# Error inflating DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, layout-inflater

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
private String[] drawer_options;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    drawer_options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
   mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawer_options));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.ActionItem1).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.ActionItem1:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(drawer_options[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame"
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cliq_fragment, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }}}
```

I'm trying to start this activity from another activity using an intent. I'm not sure what's wrong or if I'm missing something because it force closes at the onCreate() I tried to look up the errors from the logcat but I haven't had any luck. Here's the logcat from when it starts this activity.

```
05-20 22:59:27.697: D/memalloc(21948): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51d88000 size:4976640 offset:4853760
05-20 22:59:27.697: D/memalloc(21948): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52247000 size:5099520 offset:4976640
05-20 22:59:27.697: D/memalloc(21948): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52724000 size:5222400 offset:5099520
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 53: Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout;.closeDrawer (Landroid/view/View;)V
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 50: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;.onConfigurationChanged (Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)V
05-20 22:59:27.727: E/dalvikvm(21948): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout', referenced from method com.example.facecliq.HomeActivity.onCreate
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 32 (Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout;) in Lcom/example/facecliq/HomeActivity;
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 51: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;.onOptionsItemSelected (Landroid/view/MenuItem;)Z
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 52: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;.syncState ()V
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 54: Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout;.isDrawerOpen (Landroid/view/View;)Z
05-20 22:59:27.727: W/dalvikvm(21948): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/facecliq/HomeActivity$1; (30)
05-20 22:59:27.737: W/dalvikvm(21948): Link of class 'Lcom/example/facecliq/HomeActivity$1;' failed
05-20 22:59:27.757: W/dalvikvm(21948): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9e1f8)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.facecliq/com.example.facecliq.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at com.example.facecliq.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    ... 11 more
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: For some reason eclipse disassociated private libraries with this project. Upon re-adding and cleaning it no longer blows up at the onCreate()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest revision of the support library(13) which is what contains the DrawerLayout and other relevant classes. Copy the .jar for the support library to the /libs folder of your project. Finally, Update ADT to the latest version.  Logcat is complaining

```
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 05-20 22:59:27.777: E/AndroidRuntime(21948): at


Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout', referenced from method com.example.facecliq.HomeActivity.onCreate
```

Answer (score 3):

Its something av noticed after updating my ADT. To solve this just make sure if you have referenced any external libraries in your project, you should ensure that they are ticked under Order and Export. Left click project> click Java Build Path>Order and Export> check Android Private Libraries

Comment: Just adding to this - I ended up checking everything available (Android Private Libraries + Android 4.2 Libraries) and the I had to *clean* and then build.